# Ruby code qn. How to decrease iteration

Tags: ruby, iteration

I'm new to ruby and I'm wondering why this error comes up. (Sorry for bad formatting)

**Error:**

```
rb37: in '%': nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
```

And also I need help with my question. I'm suppose to come up with a method to run through a list of 1 million ID numbers to find a specific ID using the most efficient way possible (in less than 5min). I've been at this the whole afternoon :(

```
def exist?(id)
    dump = []
    employee_list = $employee_list.sort    #employee_list is an array of 1 million lines of data, I have to look for a specific "id"

    while dump.length < id
        dump << employee_list.first 

        if dump.last != id 
            if id%dump.last != 0 && dump.last != 1
                 employee_list.delete_if { |n| n%dump.last == 0 }
 #what im doing here is to delete ID from employee_list that are multiples of n 
            elsif id%dump.last == 0 
                employee_list.delete_if { |m| m%dump.last == 0 && m!=id }
 #deleting multiples of m (excluding id itself) 
            end
        elsif dump.last == id 
            return true
        end
    end
    return false 
end
```

Comment: Do you really want to have an array with ONE MILLION items stored in memory? And sorted like this?

Comment: Its a school question exercise that ask me for a better algorithm than just using a for loop to check 1 by 1 which will take many hours.

Comment: In this case, since you have a sorted array, why don't you implement a binary search, which in pretty faster than a 1 by 1 comparison in the average case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: Looping through 1 million items takes many hours!?

Answer (score 1):

I honestly have absolutely no idea what your code is trying to do, but here's the problem: you loop until the length of your `dump` array is greater than the `id` you are searching. In the loop, you append the first element of the `employee_list` array to the end of `dump`. You also delete stuff from `employee_list`.

Now, depending on how large `id` is, you are going to loop very often. E.g. imagine `id` is, say, `1234567890`, you are going to loop over a *billion* times, and you are appending over a billion elements to your `dump` array. At the same time, you are also constantly deleting stuff from `employee_list`. It is very likely, that at some point in time, `employee_list` will become empty, which means that `employee_list.first` will become `nil`, you will append `nil` as the last element of `dump`, and thus you will try to take the modulus of `id` and `nil` in line 9, 10, 12, or 13.

Like I said, I don't actually understand what you are doing at all, so I can't tell you how to fix the problem.

Here's how I would solve the problem:

```
def exist?(id)
  $employee_list.find(id)
end
```