# Efficient algorithm for searching unsorted array

Tags: ruby, iteration

Posted my question back then and I was really unclear. Need help with this question.

Given a csv file with 1 million values inside and integer N, I have to come up with an algorithm that checks if N exists in the file, returning true if it does and false if it doesn't. The values are put into an array.

Using a for loop itself will take hours, I'm required to complete this iteration in 5 minutes.

EDIT: I came up with a code for binary search. Unfortunately this took more than 5 minutes. How can I speed up the searching process?

```
def exist?(id)
employee_list = $employee_list
mid = employee_list.length / 2

while mid != 0 and mid+1 != employee_list.length
    a = employee_list[mid]
    if a != id 
        if a > id 
            if mid<=employee_list.length/2 
                mid = mid / 2
            elsif mid>employee_list.length/2
                mid = ((mid-(employee_list.length/2))/2) + ((employee_list.length)/2)
            end
        elsif a < id 
            if mid>=employee_list.length/2
                mid = mid + ((employee_list.length-mid)/2) 
            elsif mid<employee_list.length/2
                mid = (((employee_list.length/2) - mid)/2) + mid
            end
        end
    else 
        return true
    end
end
return false 
end
```

Comment: What i have so far is to do a binary search

Comment: You cannot perform a binary search on an unsorted array

Comment: If you need to search through the array multiple times, then performing a  binary search is the correct answer - but you must first **sort** the array in order to do this. Could you please include your current attempt at solving this, in the above post?

Comment: "_back then_" – are you referring to [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39269465/477037) you've posted 4 hours ago? You can still edit it.

Comment: It seems weird to me that iterating an array with 1 million objects shoudl take hours. What kind of objects do you store in the array? How big are they? How does your condition look like?

Answer (score 1):

> Using a for loop itself will take hours

That's not true. It will take less than a second.

If you need to do it only once:

1. Use brute force (loop)

If you need it more then `logN` times:

1. Convert your array into Set/Hash
2. Check if your number exists in the Hash

Brute force will cost you `O(n)`

Binary search will cost you `O(n*log(n))` for sorting (in general case) + `O(log(n))` for search.

Using hash will cost you `O(n)` to construct `Hash` and amortized `O(1)` for lookup.

Comment: If you only need to do it once, then surely sorting it is going to take just as long as running an `include?` check?....

Comment: @TomLord yes true :), I realized it as soon as I posted my answer

Comment: so does that mean that for an unsorted array, it's impossible to search for less than O(n)

Comment: Yes, you can only parallel your calculations if you have more cores.

Answer (score -1):

Here I initialize an array of 1 million values with a random integer. And a test value of 4.

```
array = Array.new(1_000_000) { rand(1_000_000_000_000) }
test_val = 494_930_039
```

To check if there are any value in the array equal to the test value, you just need to use the `any?` method on the array. Like so,

```
array.any? {|x| x == test_val }
```

This will return either a `true` or `false`.

A benchmark test results

```
user CPU time                              0.050000s
system CPU time                            0.000000s
the sum of the user and system CPU times   0.050000s
the elapsed real time                      0.050704s
```

Comment: This answer misses the point. You have not addressed the "efficiency" question, and your benchmarks are highly misleading. The reason that this is so "fast" is that because your big array only contains the digits `0-10`, so the `array.any?` method will only check, on average, 11 values.

Comment: i updated the rand function to generate value from 0 to 1,000,000,000,000  (exclusive), speed is still good.

Comment: but still misleading since efficiency is a comparison of one method to another. Benchmarking a single method shows its own performance but not its efficiency by comparison.

Comment: You're still missing the point. You have still not addressed he question of "what's the most efficient method?", and your benchmark is **still** meaningless since it is dependant on where in the random array the value `494_930_039` happened to appear, this time. You would need to run the test many times and get an average result.

Comment: "I'm required to complete this iteration in 5 minutes" is part of the question, that is what I am comparing my method to

Comment: `array = [...]; test_val = 123; array.include?(test_val)`. This is equally fast as your code, and is an absolutely trivial answer. My interpretation of the question is "What if I want to keep looking through the array for lots of values?" - and your answer does not even attempt to address the performance implications of this.

Comment: there is supposedly an algorithm that eliminates the need to iterate through every single value (as hinted by my prof). Been half a day into this and i've yet to come up with anything.

Comment: @TomLord, I think that's where we differed, I interpreted his question as looking for a single number in the array.

Comment: @Clement: I think your professor hints at using set/hash.